# QuickLook plugin not getting noticed

Tags: macos, quicklook

I have a QuickLook plugin which I have successfully debugged and gotten working under the `qlmanage` tool. I have added the plugin to my application, at `Contents/Library/QuickLook/`, and I also tried putting it in `/Library/QuickLook`. But the OS isn't noticing my plugin.

The Finder doesn't show thumbnails for my files, and `qlmanage -m` doesn't list anything related to my plugin or file types.

I tried running `qlmanage -r` to reset the QL cache, and then launching my application to try to get the OS to notice that there's a QL plugin in there.

I have put all the required document type and UTI info in my Info.plist. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check your generator's Info.plist using `plutil -lint` and my own free [InfoPlistChecker](http://www.jwwalker.com/pages/infoplistchecker.html).

Comment: Thanks, InfoPlistChecker found my problem. Somehow I ended up with my Imported UTIs entry having the children for document types instead. I corrected that, restarted my Finder, and now I have my thumbnails.